# What is the best data structure to store synchronize data to be shared across multiple android devices?

Tags: android, data-structures, data-synchronization

My project is about connecting multiple android devices and help them communicate with each other. I have connected all these devices using bluetooth. One device acts as a server and rest of them as clients. The devices are able to send and receive messages/events and do certain tasks upon receiving messages.

Now I want synchronize a data list among all the connected devices. Since there is already a channel open between the devices, I would like to use it to send synchronization events/data so that all the devices are in sync. The sync data list will mostly have the list of devices connected, their status, the list of events which they are interested. I want to create a format or a structure for this data list.

The data list will be shared at the beginning when the connections are setup and also when there is any update on any of the fields.

For example:

The data list must have the below details:

```
Device - Server
Status - Connected
Events - eventA, eventB

Device - Client1
Status - Connected
Events - eventA

Device - Client2
Status - Connected
Events - eventB

Device - Client3
Status - Connected
Events - eventA, eventB
```

The main idea behind this is that for example, if client3 is going to publish eventB, then it will send the event only to server and client2. So basically this list will act as a look up before sending any event/message.

What is the best way to store these data in android? Can android bundle or List be able to store this? Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but you will likely want to use a server for operations with synchronous data.